# JQuery `length` property not working properly. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[**JSFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/3buve19w/5/).

In the following SSCCE, in the `click` listener for `button#remove`, there is a `alert("numberOfRows:" + numberOfRows); //check*****************` statement. The statement before it calculates `numberOfRows`. This number *always* appears to be `0`. The question is about it.

Please run this code. Click the `Add TextField` button once or more than once. Each click will add the Orange bordered table. THEN click the `Remove TextField` button, and you will get the `alert`. The problem is that this will always show the `numberOfRows` to be `0`, no matter how many rows are actually there.

**The question is why? How do I fix this?**

```js
$(document).on("click", "button.remove", function() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var currentRow = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
  currentRow.remove();


  //update numberOfRows variable
  var parentTable = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();

  var numberOfRows = parentTable.children('tbody').children('tr').length;

  /*****************************************/
  /*****************************************/
  /*****************************************/
  alert("numberOfRows:" + numberOfRows); //check*****************
  /*****************************************/
  /*****************************************/
  /*****************************************/


  if (!(numberOfRows > 1)) {
    $(".remove").hide();
  }
});










$(document).on("click", "button.add", function() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var parentTable = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
  var lastTableRow = parentTable.children('tbody').children('tr:last');

  //Adding the new row
  parentTable.children('tbody').append(lastTableRow.clone());

  //Reset lastRow variable 
  lastTableRow = parentTable.children('tbody').children('tr:last');
  //Reset the fields
  lastTableRow.find('table tbody tr td input').each(function() {
    $(this).val('');
  });


  //update numberOfRows variable
  var numberOfRows = parentTable.children('tbody').children('tr').length;
  alert("numberOfRows:" + numberOfRows); //check


  if (!(numberOfRows > 1)) {
    $(".remove").hide();
  } else {
    $(".remove").show();
  }

});
```

```css
#outer-table {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 3px solid pink;
}
#inner-table {
  border: 3px solid orange;
}
.remove {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="outer-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>


        <table id="inner-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p style="display:inline-block">Enter first complain:</p>
                <input type="text" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <button class="add" id="add">Add Textfield</button>
                <button class="remove" id="remove">Remove Textfield</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>



      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>



  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Table Footer</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

</table>
```

Comment: Whatever the actual problem here might be – there _must_ be a better way to traverse up to the designated element than `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()`

Comment: Whenever you find yourself doing `.parent().parent().parent().par.....` etc. you're doing something wrong

Comment: Change the order: define parentTable before you delete the current row.

Comment: Also, ID's are unique, and can only be used once, even on inserted elements.

Comment: @adeneo Could you suggest a better way?

Comment: somehting like .parents("table").parents("tr");

Comment: @adeneo I changed the use of ID's (`#something`) with classes (`.something`) and edited the question

Comment: .closest(selector) would work great here also.

Comment: @NineBerry I don't know why, but your solution seems to work. Can you post that as an answer? I'll mark it as accepted answer

Comment: also fiddle wasn't working for your click handler... use function(event) { }

Comment: why don't you create a new element instead of cloning the last one, like that you could give it a unique id like the row number and delete it directly from the button `$("row1")...;` give the button the id of the row number too, so you do something like `$("row" + $(this).attr("id"))...` to delete the element row...

Comment: Rockerest has written a good explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is what it should look like

```js
$('.outer-table').on("click", ".add", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var row = $(this).closest('.inner-table').closest('tr'),
        rows = row.closest('tbody').children('tr').length + 1;

    row.after(row.clone());

    alert("numberOfRows:" + rows);

    $(".remove").toggle(rows > 1);
});

$('.outer-table').on("click", ".remove", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var row = $(this).closest('.inner-table').closest('tr'),
        rows = row.closest('tbody').children('tr').length - 1;

    row.remove();

    alert("numberOfRows:" + rows);

    if (rows < 2) $(".remove").hide();
});
```

```css
.outer-table {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 3px solid pink;
}

.inner-table {
    border: 3px solid orange;
}

.remove {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="outer-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="inner-table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p style="display:inline-block">Enter first complaint :</p>
                                <input type="text" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <button class="add">Add Textfield</button>
                                <button class="remove">Remove Textfield</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Table Footer</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, use `.closest( "table" )` to get the parent table.
And `.closest( "tr" )` for the row.

> If you **must** really have nested tables, then you can still use `.closest( "table" ).parents( "table" );` but this should be a serious red flag.

Finally, the reason it's not working is because you are removing the context of the remove click handler (the button) from the DOM with:

```
currentRow.remove();
```

And then immediately trying to navigate up the DOM tree with:

```
var parentTable = $(this).parent()[... snip ... ].parent();
```

However, `$( this ).parent()...` no longer exists, because you've deleted it.

In this scenario, `.length` *should* be 0, because your DOM navigation returns nothing.

If you fetch the parent table first, and then delete the row, it should work.